# VB2010: Allow Float/Integers, Backspace, and Range of Value in Textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've one Textbox in Visual Basic (Visual Studio 2010, .net frame work 4.0)
Now I have a problem!
I want that user only Enter Integer, float, backspace and range of value?
Confused?
Oh yeah
I want that user only Enter value in between 0 - 4 (value may be in decimal as 3.49)
Now I want complete code:
I have this:
This is working , but I am unable to specifies the range between 0-4

> Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
>   System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
>
> ```
>         Dim FullStop As Char
>         FullStop = "."
>
>         ' if the '.' key was pressed see if there already is a '.' in the string
>         ' if so, dont handle the keypress
>
>         If e.KeyChar = FullStop And TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(FullStop) <> -1 Then
>             e.Handled = True
>             Return
>         End If
>
>         ' If the key aint a digit
>         If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
>             ' verify whether special keys were pressed
>             ' (i.e. all allowed non digit keys - in this example
>             ' only space and the '.' are validated)
>             If (e.KeyChar <> FullStop) And
>                (e.KeyChar <> Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back)) Then
>                 ' if its a non-allowed key, dont handle the keypress
>                 e.Handled = True
>                 Return
>             End If
>         End If
> End Sub
> ```

Please if some one give me the complete code for this so I will be very happy
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the Benifits of `ascii codes` of `characters` to solve your problem,
Try this out, If you have any doubts in the following implementation, then feel free to comment me back.

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

        'Ascii code 8 for backspace -- Ascii code 46 for (. period)
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Then

            'If typed character is a period then we have to ensure that more than one of it
            'Should not get allowed to type. And also we have to check whether the period symbol
            'may cause any conflicts with MaxNo that is 4
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Then
                If TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Or Val(TextBox1.Text.Trim & e.KeyChar) >= 4 Then
                    e.Handled = True
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                'If pressed key is backspace, then allow it.
                Exit Sub
            End If

        End If

        'Checking whether user typing more than 4 or not.
        If Val(TextBox1.Text.Trim & e.KeyChar) > 4 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

        '48 - 57  = Ascii codes for numbers
        If (Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Wah!!!<br>
Amazing!<br>
This is really working, Thanks a lot<br>
Thanks for ur time
Jazakallah :)

Comment: And hy one thing plz if u wana tell me, From where i learn there asci value that for backspace is this abd blah blah......................?
And also i want to learn vb.net advance, i read about 5 books but still i am really very weak in that, so my question is that from where i learn and what is the name of the book which will help me. I want to like u (As this is hard :p)

Comment: @xXcramaXerXx It seems that you are very enthusiastic to learn a programming language, This kind of attitude will help you to get a firm grip on what you are looking for. Any way, Dont always rely on books, Do some projects on your own. If you get stuck then get advises from experts. I'm sure that, It will automatically improve your skills. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you very much for ur Help, I am really very happy to communicate with expert like u, Yeah i want to, I've completed different projects but still I hesistates in diffrent occasions, it means i am still nOOb, thats why i am asking for book or good place from where i learn it step by step, Thanks Again